# What is the origin of the 'Light' as a ghost?

Tags: folklore, origins, afterlife, ghosts

As a ghost (or after death), it is popularly believed that you will see a light and that light will take you to the afterlife. Where, and/or when, does this 'light' emerge in folklore's history?

Comment: Off-hand, my guess is the curretn popularity of this concept is due to the 1982 film [Poltergeist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist_(1982_film)).  The formalization of the idea probably arose out of [Spiritualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiritualism), and anecdotal accounts of near-death experiences reporting a "light at the end of the tunnel."

Comment: This might help: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314848/light-at-the-end-of-the-tunnel-earliest-occurence